# Delete element form object and Re index and add new element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to remove 0 index element and I want re-index and also add new element I created objects like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var offline_rijksmuseum_adult_barcode_array = {};
<?php
$data['2018']= ['852','896','787'];
$data['2019']= ['185','208'];
foreach($data as $key => $result) {
 ?>
 var sub_array = {};
 <?php
 foreach($result as $keyz => $r) { ?>   
    sub_array['<?php echo $keyz; ?>'] = "<?php echo $r; ?>";
<?php
 }
 ?> 
    offline_rijksmuseum_adult_barcode_array['<?php echo $key; ?>'] = sub_array;
<?php
 } ?>

console.log(offline_rijksmuseum_adult_barcode_array);

2018:{0: "852", 1: "896", 2: "787"}
2019:{0: "185", 1: "208"}
```

I want Delete 0 index element and reindx and also add insert new element at the end I want output like

```
   2018:{0: "896", 1: "787", 2: "6985"}
   2019:{0: "208", 1: "209"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use array data type if you want to deal with indexes. I have changed the output little bit in below snippets, which should work for your scenario -

```js
let data = {
  2018: ["896", "787", "6985"] //changed to array intead of object
};

//to remove index 0, with auto reindexing
data[2018].shift();
console.log(data);


//to append at the end
data[2018].push("111");
console.log(data);
```